# Geolocation permission in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How could i use geolocation permissions on android studio ? I know that there are already questions for this, but none of theses works for me. I already tried this :

```java
public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

public class GeoWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin,
                    GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {

        callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
    }
}

WebView mWebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl(myUrl);
}
```

But it didn't work. I don't know what to do and i am not confident with java, so it is possible that i made dumb errors.
I also tried to add this which asked me the permissions but got geolocation error: insufficient permissions:

```java
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 2);
}
```

Comment: @ModusTollens With the condition on the second part of the code, it asks me the permission but i still dont have enough perms after clicking yes , and without this part it asks me nothing and i dont have the perms anyways ( the error is error : insuffisant permissions)

Comment: *＋1* for removing the Samba configuration question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the condition works, i just added it to the wrong place and not at the beginning of `onCreate()`.